# How to programmatically set logLevel for group of loggers of one package with log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

How to programmatically set logLevel for group of loggers of one package?

This variant does not work
`Configurator.setLevel("com.something.packwirhloggers", Level.ERROR)`

How can I implement it? With filters? or maybe kind of wildcards?

Interesting that strictly named configuration change level work,
for example, I can do
`Configurator.setLevel("com.something.packwirhloggers.SomeLogger", Level.ERROR)`

But for package... I do not know. And I can not find an answer in official docks. But I believe that it is not something irregular)

Answer (score 0):

.addAttribute("additivity", true) solved my problem